# How to achive deploy on save of multi-module Maven project in NetBeans?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I have a multi-module Maven project in NetBeans with the following structure in file system.

```
.
| MyProject/
├── web-module/
|   ├── src/
|   └── pom.xml
├── core-module/
|   ├── src/
|   └── pom.xml
└── pom.xml
```

I set Compile on Save on all the modules and Deploy on Save in web-module and now when I change something in web-module it's automatically compiled and deployed but it doesn't work for changes in core-module.
I also created a new project group (File/Project Groups.../Projects and All Required Projects) and set the parent project there but it doesn't work as well.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible at all to achieve what I want in NetBeans and, if yess, how?
2. Deploy on Save in NB seems to restart Tomcat which is not a efficient solution (Spring context loading time) — is it possible to use something like "jvm hot swap", namely when I put some changes (I mean changes inside a method, not changing class structure), I'd like to see this immediately without restarting Tomcat.

I use NetBeans 8, Maven embedded in NB and Tomcat 6

PS. I know what I want to achieve is not a rocket science, I was able to configure Eclipse this way and everything was working decently (without installing any additional plugins).

PPS. Yeah, I've heard about JRebel but it's not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Java debugger settings, the "Apply code changes after save" should be enabled.

[image]

This will allow you to update classes without restarts, but only limited to method body changes.

Note that there were a few [bugs](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=176221) reported about this feature in NetBeans, I'm not aware if this problem was solved or not.

EDIT: disable "Deploy on Save" via Project properties -> Run tab.

Comment: Thanks, it works. One note for others which may have the same problem, Deploy on save in the web module (the one which is deployed to Tomcat) properties has to be unchecked in order to use this solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, this requires one to use a debugger session for this to work, resource file alterations are not allow changes more than method bodies.